# Invoking Web API method(PUT,DELETE) using an WebClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created two project

1. MVC4 with WebAPI project
2. WebAPI Project

I am calling WebAPI PUT/DELETE methods from the MVC project using a controller but I am not able to update data using PUT and it is returning a 404 error. I am using `webClient` instead of `HttpClient`.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{

    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
    var result = client.UploadString(url, "PUT", data);
}

public void Put(string id, Customer _objCustomer)
{

}
```

I have read many tutorials but I am still facing the same issue. How can I resolve this cross domain issue through `webClient`? I haven't found a sample application where they implemented PUT/DELETE using `webclient`.

Comment: Use `HttpClient`, which is much better.

Comment: Does the PUT request work using other methods, like Fiddler for example?

Comment: no,its showing 404 not found.did you get same issue before.how to fix?

Comment: It doesn't matter which client you are using. Post here  how your Web API service is implemented and how routes are mapped. Problem is that you are calling incorrect URL+Verb+Body

Comment: please share the sample project if anybody have?it would be greatful

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to place a `[HttpPut]` attribute on your "Put" action.
Please name you actions better.

Comment: this is not the problem.